# Need help in dividing a set into different pairs

Tags: permutations, gcd-and-lcm, set-partition

In how many ways can you divide the set of eight numbers {2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9} into 4 pairs such that no pair of numbers has G.C.D equal to 2?

Comment: Any thoughts?  Hint to get you started:  First argue that the $2$ must be paired with an odd number.

Comment: I can't seem to get hold of the total number of ways in which we can divide the set. I know that the cases can be made in many ways, one of them being that all the even numbers paired with the odd numbers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given this set of numbers, the only way for a pair of them to have a greatest common denominator of $2$ would be for both of them to be even... with one exception. We are allowed to pair $(4, 8)$, because in this case they will have a GCD of $4$, not $2$.

So let's split this problem into (a) the cases where $(4, 8)$ are not a pair, and (b) the cases where $(4, 8)$ are a pair.

In case (a), we have to pair each even number with an odd number. So our pairs are $(2, \_)$, $(4, \_)$, $(6, \_)$, and $(8, \_)$. We have to place the four remaining odd numbers $\{3, 5, 7, 9\}$ into these blanks. So there are $4! = 24$ total possibilities here.

In case (b), we know that $(4, 8)$ are a pair. However we still aren't allowed to make the pair $(2, 6)$, as these would have a GCD of $2$. But other than this, anything is game. The remaining numbers are $\{2, 3, 5, 6, 7, 9\}$. Let's think of the pairs this time as $(2, \_)$, $(6, \_)$, and $(\_, \_)$ There are $4$ options for the first blank, $3$ options for the second blank, and after this the last two are determined. This makes $4\cdot 3 = 12$ possibilities here.

So all in all, I count $24+12=36$ total possible ways.

---

EDIT: you can also verify that this reasoning is correct by exhaustively listing all 36 possible pairings. Here are the ones I came up with:

```
1:  (2, 3) (4, 5) (6, 7) (8, 9)
2:  (2, 3) (4, 5) (6, 9) (7, 8)
3:  (2, 3) (4, 7) (5, 6) (8, 9)
4:  (2, 3) (4, 7) (5, 8) (6, 9)
5:  (2, 3) (4, 8) (5, 6) (7, 9)
6:  (2, 3) (4, 8) (5, 7) (6, 9)
7:  (2, 3) (4, 8) (5, 9) (6, 7)
8:  (2, 3) (4, 9) (5, 6) (7, 8)
9:  (2, 3) (4, 9) (5, 8) (6, 7)
10: (2, 5) (3, 4) (6, 7) (8, 9)
11: (2, 5) (3, 4) (6, 9) (7, 8)
12: (2, 5) (3, 6) (4, 7) (8, 9)
13: (2, 5) (3, 6) (4, 8) (7, 9)
14: (2, 5) (3, 6) (4, 9) (7, 8)
15: (2, 5) (3, 7) (4, 8) (6, 9)
16: (2, 5) (3, 8) (4, 7) (6, 9)
17: (2, 5) (3, 8) (4, 9) (6, 7)
18: (2, 5) (3, 9) (4, 8) (6, 7)
19: (2, 7) (3, 4) (5, 6) (8, 9)
20: (2, 7) (3, 4) (5, 8) (6, 9)
21: (2, 7) (3, 5) (4, 8) (6, 9)
22: (2, 7) (3, 6) (4, 5) (8, 9)
23: (2, 7) (3, 6) (4, 8) (5, 9)
24: (2, 7) (3, 6) (4, 9) (5, 8)
25: (2, 7) (3, 8) (4, 5) (6, 9)
26: (2, 7) (3, 8) (4, 9) (5, 6)
27: (2, 7) (3, 9) (4, 8) (5, 6)
28: (2, 9) (3, 4) (5, 6) (7, 8)
29: (2, 9) (3, 4) (5, 8) (6, 7)
30: (2, 9) (3, 5) (4, 8) (6, 7)
31: (2, 9) (3, 6) (4, 5) (7, 8)
32: (2, 9) (3, 6) (4, 7) (5, 8)
33: (2, 9) (3, 6) (4, 8) (5, 7)
34: (2, 9) (3, 7) (4, 8) (5, 6)
35: (2, 9) (3, 8) (4, 5) (6, 7)
36: (2, 9) (3, 8) (4, 7) (5, 6)
```

Comment: what about $(2,3)(4,5)(6,8)(7,9)$ and $(2, 3) (4, 7) (5, 9) (6,8)$ and  several others.

Comment: (6, 8) have a GCD of 2 and are therefore not permitted

Comment: Oh,.... right..... Hmm.... I must have double counted somewhere.  I figure $2$ must pair with an odd and $6$must pair with an odd so there are $4*3$ ways to do that.  There are four remaining numbers and ${4\choose 2}=6$ ways to do that.  So I get $4*3*6=72$.  But I don't see how I double counted.

Comment: "$4$ may (but doesn't have to be) paired with $8$ and there are no other restrictions." -> this basically means you are putting no restrictions at all on $4$, but you cannot pair $4$ with either $2$ or $6$.

Comment: That wasn't my error.  There is no restriction on $4$ or $8$ *after* $2$ and $6$ had been paired up with odds.  My error was simply in counting the last two pairs I counted the *pairs* of pairs as ordered; I counted $(a,b)(c,d)$ separately from $(c,d)(a,b)$.

Comment: Yep, I wasn't able to edit my comment in time haha. Cf. the comments on your post.

Comment: BTW you don't need to split into cases if $4,8$ are paired.  If we not that neither $2$ nor $6$ may pair with odds you have $(2,-),(6,-)(4,-)(-,-)$ given There are $4$ odd options for the $2$ and $3$ odd options for the $6$ then $3$ total options for the $4$ (which include $8$ as a possibility).

Answer (score 0):

$2$ must be paired with an odd number.

$6$ can not be paired with an even number that doesn't also have three as a divisor so $6$ must be paired with an odd number.

$4$ may (but doesn't have to be) paired with $8$ and there are no other restrictions.

There are $4$ odd numbers to pair with TWO.

And after that there are $3$ remaining odd numbers to pair with SIX.

And for the remaining four numbers there are ${4\choose 2}$ ways to choose a the third pair and ${2 \choose 2} =1$ way to choose the last pair.

But choosing $(a,b)$ then $(c,d)$ is the same as $(c,d) $ then $(a,b)$ so this is double counting.  There are $\frac 62 = 3$ ways to choose the final two pairs.

(Alternatively given any of the $4$ remaining unpaired numbers there are $3$ numbers we can pair with it.  And the remaining to numbers must pair together.)

So there are $4*3*3 = 36$ such ways.

Comment: 4 cannot be paired with 2 or 6 as GCD(4, 2) = GCD(4, 6) = 2; this is a restriction which should be counted.

Comment: No... that is fine because $2$ and $6$ have been paired up with odd so that's not an option to have $2$ with or $6$ with $4$.  The error is the order of choosing the third and fourth pair doesn't matter. I have $6$ choices for the third pair but it doesn't matter that the same as if I chose it's complement as the third pair.  Rookie error.

Comment: Yep, you're right, that is it indeed.